# pt size in react native

Tags: react-native, screen-resolution

In react native, I use this code to get the screen size(Nexus 5x virtual device)

```
const screenWidth = React.Dimensions.get('window').width;

const screenHeight = React.Dimensions.get('window').height;
```

And I get screenWidth = 411,screenHeight = 683.

I guess it means 411 pt and 683 pt, then I google that and found 1 pt = 1/72 inches.

Because Nexus 5x virtual device is 5.2 inch and 411*1/72 > 5.2. So I guess the two pt mentioned are different things?

I want to know if I can use 411 pt to get the size to inches?Like, 411pt = x inches